# SessionHandlerInterface not found when deploy Drupal 10

Tags: drupal

I've moved a website powered by Drupal 10 from local server (where everything worked fine) to remote, configured PHP 8.2 at the latter, but when I run the website in the browser I get the error

```
Interface "SessionHandlerInterface" not found in .../core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/SessionHandler.php on line 15
```

What else should I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've just found out that I should install `php82-session`. Now it's working